# up to how much memory limit can be set POST method in PHP? Maximum how much?

Tags: php

Normally 8mb is default memory limit of POST method..how much we can set? up to GB is possible or less than that? can we send large video of 4 gig through POST method?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) doesn't specify any limits for post requests, so the limits will either come from

- Your web server configuration (.htaccess)
- Your PHP configuration (php.ini)
- The client (browser)

I just performed a small test locally and I was able to upload a 9.1GB video file using Apache, PHP 7 and Google Chrome.